# conditional code chunks in a bquote call?

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I have a function such as this one :

```r
redondant_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  if(cond) {
    bquote({
      some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x))
      do_something()
      some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))
    })
  } else {
    bquote({
      some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x))
      some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))
    })
  }
}

redondant_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     do_something()
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
redondant_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
```

It works well but as its name indicates it's redundant, in real use cases there isa lot of copy and pasted code, this doesn't look good.

I can build these expressions in order not to repeat my code chunks :

```r
awkward_code_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  start <- bquote(some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x)))
  end   <- bquote(some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y)))
  if(cond) {
    bquote({
      .(start)
      do_something()
      .(end)})
  } else  {
    bquote({
      .(start)
      .(end)})
  }
}

awkward_code_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     do_something()
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
awkward_code_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
```

But we lost all the beauty of `bquote()`, my code isn't written in order and if I have several conditional chunks this will look terrible.

Another way would be to place the test inside the expression:

```r
ugly_output_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  bquote({
    some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x))
    if(.(cond)) do_something()
    some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))
  })
}

ugly_output_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     if (TRUE) 
#>         do_something()
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
ugly_output_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     if (FALSE) 
#>         do_something()
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
```

The code looks good but the output doesn't, who wants `if (TRUE)` and `if (FALSE)` in code ?

We can get around this by using the `if` inside of the `.()` :

```r
ugly_code_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  bquote({
    some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x))
    .(if(cond) quote(do_something()) else NULL
    some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))
  })
}

ugly_code_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     do_something()
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
ugly_code_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     NULL
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
```

The output now looks good, but my code has some nested `bquote()`, `.()`, `if`, `quote()` calls, and a disgraceful `NULL`, it's not very elegant.

How do I get both clean code and a clean output ?

Answer (score 2):

I propose to re-implement `bquote()` with an additional feature `.IF(cond, yes, no)` (with optional `no`), `yes` and `no` will be quoted automatically and `no` will default to `quote(expr=)` (i.e. the "missing" object), so the logic of the code is not polluted by `quote()` calls and we minimize bracket overload.

See results first and function code at the bottom :

```
happy_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  bquote2({
    some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x))
    .IF(cond, do_something())
    some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))
  })
}


happy_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     do_something()
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
happy_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#> {
#>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#> }
```

**code**

```r
bquote2 <- function (expr, where = parent.frame(), splice = FALSE) 
{
  if (!is.environment(where)) 
    where <- as.environment(where)
  unquote <- function(e) {
    if (is.pairlist(e)) 
      as.pairlist(lapply(e, unquote))
    else if (is.call(e)) {
      if (is.name(e[[1L]]) && as.character(e[[1]]) == ".") 
        eval(e[[2L]], where)
      # EDIT 1 STARTS HERE
      else if (is.name(e[[1L]]) && as.character(e[[1]]) == ".IF") {
        cond <- eval(e[[2L]], where)
        if(cond) {
          unquote(e[[3L]])
        } else {
          if (length(e) == 4) {
            unquote(e[[4L]])
          } else {
            NULL
          }
        }
      # EDIT 1 ENDS HERE
      } else if (splice) {
        if (is.name(e[[1L]]) && as.character(e[[1L]]) == 
            "..") 
          stop("can only splice inside a call", 
               call. = FALSE)
        else as.call(unquote.list(e))
      }
      else {
        # EDIT 2 STARTS HERE
        e <- as.call(lapply(e, unquote))
        if(is.name(e[[1L]]) && as.character(e[[1]]) == "{") {
          for(i in rev(seq_along(e)[-1])) {
            if(is.null(e[[i]])) e[[i]] <- NULL
          }
        }
        e
        # EDIT 2 ENDS HERE
      }
    }
    else e
  }
  is.splice.macro <- function(e) is.call(e) && is.name(e[[1L]]) && 
    as.character(e[[1L]]) == ".."
  unquote.list <- function(e) {
    p <- Position(is.splice.macro, e, nomatch = NULL)
    if (is.null(p)) 
      lapply(e, unquote)
    else {
      n <- length(e)
      head <- if (p == 1) 
        NULL
      else e[1:(p - 1)]
      tail <- if (p == n) 
        NULL
      else e[(p + 1):n]
      macro <- e[[p]]
      mexp <- eval(macro[[2L]], where)
      if (!is.vector(mexp)) 
        stop("can only splice vectors")
      c(lapply(head, unquote), mexp, as.list(unquote.list(tail)))
    }
  }
  unquote(substitute(expr))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option in this case seems to be to remove the unwanted expression afterwards using `[`:

```r
awkward_code_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  out <- bquote({
    some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x))
    do_something()
    some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))
  })
  if(cond) out else out[-3]
}

awkward_code_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     do_something()
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
awkward_code_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
```

or using `substitute` which saves the `.()`:

```r
awkward_code_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  out <- substitute({
    some_long_code_chunk_1(x)
    do_something()
    some_long_code_chunk_2(y)
  })
  if(cond) out else out[-3]
}

awkward_code_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     do_something()
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
awkward_code_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
```

An alternative related to your own answer is to use `substitute` instead having assigned `do_something`:

```r
awkward_code_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  do_something <- if(cond) quote(do_something()) else quote(expr = )
  substitute({
    some_long_code_chunk_1(x)
    do_something
    some_long_code_chunk_2(y)
  })
}

awkward_code_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     do_something()
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
awkward_code_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R> 
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
```

Another option seems to be to build the expression on call at a time:

```r
awkward_code_fun <- function(x, y, cond) {
  add_to_quote <- function(x, y){
    x[length(x) + 1] <- as.expression(y)
    x
  }
  
  out <- bquote({ some_long_code_chunk_1(.(x)) })
  if(cond)
    out <- add_to_quote(out, expression(do_something()))
  add_to_quote(out, bquote(some_long_code_chunk_2(.(y))))
}

awkward_code_fun(1, 2, TRUE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     do_something()
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
awkward_code_fun(1, 2, FALSE)
#R> {
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_1(1)
#R>     some_long_code_chunk_2(2)
#R> }
```

Comment: Thanks, FYI the solutions using `quote(expr=)` don't work because they can't be evaluated properly, `{` must not have missing arguments. When we skip lines in code the parser ignores them so it's a bit counter intuitive, but since we are manipulating expressions directly we can't leave "gaps". I've edited the question and answer to reflect this.